# Mastercard Work around for third party cookies disabled users

Tags: c#, cookies, payment-gateway, 3d-secure, mastercard

I am using mastercard securecode and some of my customers are not able to complete the payments as they have there third party cookies disabled and they face this error message :

> **An error has occurred processing your payment.**
>
> *Cookies are not turned on in your Browser To access the payment pages*
>   *you need to have cookies enabled. Our cookies are only used to*
>   *identify you while you are making your payment. They are stored*
>   *temporarily as a short text string in your browser.*
>
> *All browsers are configured differently, so check your browser's help*
>   *on enabling cookies.*
>
> **Click the continue button to retry your payment once you have cookies**
>   **enabled.**

Now I need a workaround for this,ie I need to redirect users to mastercard site or need payment processing in the background such that the payment happens succefully without the problem of third party cookies.Is this possible,Please help.

I have tried this to do the payment in the background but here also the response is giving the same result for third party cookies.

Answer (score 1):

SecureCode regulations demand that the card holder interact directly with the Issuer (MasterCard). Therefore you can't proxy the request as you tried. And you're right, cookies are mandatory for that service. So the only option you have is NOT sending the shopper to SecureCode if he doesn't have cookies enabled, and just process his order regularly.

Comment: but is this possible that we send all other billing details to mastercard site and user has to enter just the pin there and after successful payment user is redirected to the return URL specified while posting ?